# Caesar Cipher JS: Why does using continue to ignore a space result in undefined?

Tags: javascript

in my code I check for the special cases `'Z' 'z'` and `' '` in a string to handle appropriately using conditional statements. In the first cases, if these characters appears I set them to `'A' 'a'` in respect. If `' '` appears, I use `continue` with the intention of going to the next iteration and to preserve the white space. However, instead of preserving the white space, I get `undefined` om the string.

```
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var finalString = "";

// Take each character in a given String and shift one letter up in the alphabet
function shiftString() {
  var userString;
  var storeString = Array();
  userString = document.getElementById('string').value;
  if (typeof userString === 'string') {              // JS must interpret user input as a string
    for (var i = 0; i < userString.length; i++) {   // Iterate through each character in given string
      if (userString.charAt(i) == 'z') {            // If we reach the end of the alphabet, start over at the beginning
        userString.charAt[i] = 'a';
      }
      else if (userString.charAt(i) == 'Z') {
        userString.charAt[i] = 'A';
      }
      else if (userString.charAt(i) == ' ') {       // Keep spaces as they are
        continue; // This results in a string such as 'HelloundefinedWorld'
      }
      else                                          // Shift to the next character over
        userString.charAt[i] = (String.fromCharCode(userString.charCodeAt(i) + 1));
      }
      console.log(typeof userString)
      return displayResult(userString);
    }
}

// Take the end result of the translated String and post it to the DOM
function displayResult(a) {
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    finalString += a.charAt[i];
  }
  result.innerHTML = finalString;
}

function clearResult() {
  result.innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: It's better using regular expression with `replace` method.

Comment: `charAt[i]`: you are doing it wrong. Gotta choose between `charAt()` and `[]`.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your script. One would be that you are returning inside the `for` loop.

Comment: Another one is that `userString.charAt[i]` does nothing and neither would assigning a value to `userString.charAt(i)` or `userString[i]` because strings are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified the code and corrected the mistakes including those mentioned in the comments. Also used `substr()` function for the character replacement. Seems to work now. Check it out:

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result');
shiftString();

// Take each character in a given String and shift one letter up in the alphabet
function shiftString() {
  var userString = document.getElementById('string').value;
  if (typeof userString === 'string') {              // JS must interpret user input as a string
    for (var i = 0; i < userString.length; i++) {   // Iterate through each character in given string
      if (userString.charAt(i) == 'z') {            // If we reach the end of the alphabet, start over at the beginning
        userString = userString.substr(0, i) + 'a' + userString.substr(i + 1);
      }
      else if (userString.charAt(i) == 'Z') {        
        userString = userString.substr(0, i) + 'A' + userString.substr(i + 1);
      }
      else if (userString.charAt(i) == ' ') {       // Keep spaces as they are
        continue; // This results in a string such as 'HelloundefinedWorld'
      }
      else{                                          // Shift to the next character over
        var newChar = String.fromCharCode(userString.charCodeAt(i) + 1);
        userString = userString.substr(0, i) + newChar + userString.substr(i + 1);
      }
    }
  result.innerHTML = userString;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="string" type="text" value="aAzZ thisIsCool"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```